# Dining Philosophers in golang

Tags: go, dining-philosophers

I'd appreciate any feedback on this code.  The assignment was to have each philosopher eat three times. I introduced time into the problem where eating takes 20 minutes and then the philosopher shouldn't eat again for at least 50 minutes.

Particularly, I'm wondering about my use of `sync.Mutex` instead of 1-length channels for synchronization. I'm also interested in feedback on my implementation of `printStatus()` where it shuts down implicitly.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type ChopS struct {
    sync.Mutex
}

type Philo struct {
    index           int
    status          string
    leftCS, rightCS *ChopS
}

func (p *Philo) eat(times_to_eat int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < times_to_eat; i++ {
        p.leftCS.Lock()
        p.rightCS.Lock()

        p.status = "eating"
        // fmt.Println("Philo", p.index, p.status)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

        p.rightCS.Unlock()
        p.leftCS.Unlock()

        p.status = "thinking"
        // Sleep for 5 seconds except after the last time to eat.
        if i < times_to_eat-1 {
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

// Print a table of philosophers
func printStatus(philos []*Philo) {

    current_time := 0.0
    fmt.Print("Time (min)")
    for _, p := range philos {
        fmt.Printf("Philo %1d     ", p.index)
    }
    fmt.Println()

    // Print status of each philosopher.  If "thinking", print nothing.
    // This makes the report easier to read
    update_interval := 500.0
    for true {
        fmt.Printf("%6.0f  ", current_time*10.0)
        for _, p := range philos {
            if p.status == "eating" {
                fmt.Printf("%9s   ", p.status)
            } else {
                fmt.Print("            ")
            }
        }
        fmt.Println()
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(update_interval) * time.Millisecond)
        current_time += update_interval / 1000.0
    }
}

const (
    NUM_PHILO    = 5
    TIMES_TO_EAT = 3
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Dining Philosopher's Problem")
    fmt.Println("Notice that at no time are two philosophers side-by-side eating.")
    fmt.Println("They eat for 20 minutes, then think for at least 50 minutes before")
    fmt.Println("eating again.")
    // Initialize
    CSticks := make([]*ChopS, NUM_PHILO)
    for i := range CSticks {
        CSticks[i] = new(ChopS)
    }
    philos := make([]*Philo, NUM_PHILO)
    for i := range philos {
        philos[i] = &Philo{i, "thinking", CSticks[i], CSticks[(i+1)%5]}
    }

    // Loop TIMES_TO_EAT times through all philosophers
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, p := range philos {
        wg.Add(1)
        go p.eat(TIMES_TO_EAT, wg)
    }

    go printStatus(philos) // This will run until the other p.eats all finish

    wg.Wait()

}
```

Comment: The lines `p.leftCS.Lock()` and `p.rightCS.Lock()` falls into the same trap as the original Dining Philosophers: they all pick up the chopstick to their left and then they all wait for the philosopher to their right to put their chopstick down, without putting down their own.